# What is the most elegant way to create a dictionary with the value as lists?

Tags: python

So I have something like

```
retval = {}

# ...
# some code here to fetch data
# ...

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    if row.someid not in retval:
        retval[row.someid] = [dict(zip(columns,rows))]
    else:
        retval[row.someid].append(dict(zip(columns,rows))
```

which yields:

```
retval = {
    1: [{'someid': 1, 'samplefield': 'valueX', ... },
        {'someid': 1, 'samplefield': 'valueY', ... }],
    2: [{'someid': 2, 'samplefield': 'valueX', ... }]
    }
```

I feel like there is a much more pythonic way to attain the result that I need.

To be precise, is there a way to reduce these lines of code:

```
if row.someid not in retval:
    retval[row.someid] = [dict(zip(columns,rows))]
else:
    retval[row.someid].append(dict(zip(columns,rows))
```

to be in a single line?

**Answer:**
It was in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) all along! Thank you to [Christian Ternus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2797476/christian-ternus) & [chthonicdaemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648033/chthonicdaemon) for pointing me in the right direction. I updated this cause I found that there could be multiple ways of doing it based on the docs.

```
from collections import defaultdict
retval = defaultdict(list) ## Or retval = defaultdict(lambda: []) based on my accepted answer.

# ...
# some code here to fetch data
# ...

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    retval[row.someid].append(dict(zip(columns,rows))
```

***OR***

```
retval = {} 

# ...
# some code here to fetch data
# ...

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    retval.setdefault(row.someid, []).append(dict(zip(columns,rows))
```

Hopes this helps you as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `defaultdict` from the builtin `collections` module:

```python
from collections import defaultdict
retval = defaultdict(lambda: [])

# ...
# some code here to fetch data
# ...

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    retval[row.someid].append(dict(zip(columns,rows))
```

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` is a bit nicer than using the `lambda`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to try it out first on my actual application before accepting as the correct answer. That was rather fast as well!

Comment: @chthonicdaemon is there a specific reason as to why defaultdict(list) is better than lambda?

Comment: @EduardDaduya It just seems a bit more direct to me, as `list` behaves *exactly* like `lambda: []`. There's a lot more machinery involved in constructing a function which returns a value than just passing through a reference to an existing object.

Comment: Thank you @chthonicdaemon for the input. I'll read up on that as well as test/time that. I did recall reading a similar doc regarding mydict = {} versus mydict = dict(), whereas mydict = {} was the preferred iirc.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Meh: In [7]: %timeit defaultdict(list)
The slowest run took 11.56 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 165 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit defaultdict(lambda: [])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 186 ns per loop
I personally think that it's a lot easier for a human reader to understand, and that's what matters.

Comment: @ChristianTernus I'll admit that I have a bit of a bias against `lambda` in general, but my argument wasn't really from a performance point of view, but rather exactly from the legibility point of view. `list` already behaves exactly like the `lambda`, and [the examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) in the docs all use the `defaultdict(type)` idiom, i.e. `defaultdict(list)`, `defaultdict(int)` and so on.

Comment: I agree that's what the docs say, but I disagree with the docs. The `defaultdict(type)` idiom is great _assuming you want the "null" value of each type_, but the minute you want something _else_ (starting at 1, for example) it gets clunky; the suggestion is to create a helper function using `itertools.repeat` (...) -- as opposed to just, say, `lambda: 1`. I think that's nuts. But reasonable people may disagree.

Comment: Thank you for linking the docs, I knew how `d.setdefault` works but I never thought that I could use it as far as `d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)`. I learned a lot in a short span of time.